# Problem using nested_form gem when save data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-forms

It's my first time here, and first time I use nested_form gem. Everything seemed to be ok, but the data from my "parent" model doesn't save.

Here is my code

```
    <%= nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p> 

      <%= f.fields_for :tasks %>
      <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>

      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

so, when I "submit", just the tasks are saved ok, but not the project name.

Any clue for me? did I miss something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields_for declaration isn't quite right

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks %>
```

Should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_builder| %>
```

you are also missing an end for that declaration and a render to render the partial that has the nested fields for the associated object.

So you should end up with something like this

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_builder| %>
  <%= render 'task_fields', :f => task_builder %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>
```

That should do the trick. all you need to do now is create a _task_field.html.erb partial and add the task fields to it in the usual way using f.label, f.text_field etc...

p.s.

Your code could not possibly have ever worked. You would have had errors so something is probably missing from your opening post.

Comment: thanks, I will try that and then I will tell you wether it works or not, but my code works and does not display any error. I followed this [example](https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples) the only "error" is I can't save the project name, but no problem with tasks. But I will try what you suggest first, thanks again for your help

Comment: OK, finally I found the problem, it was not on the forms, nor fields... It was in something I put in project model, according to a tutorial I have to write **attr_accessible :tasks_attributes** in the model file, so I remove that and everything work just fine, project name and tasks names associated to project are saved. Thanks for your help @jamesw

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the attribute. eg name to attr_accessible.

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :name,:tasks_attributes ## <-- you need this line
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but this problem was solved few months ago